# Как получить доступ к конфигурации ASP.NET Core в проекте .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, config, совместимость

Есть проект ASP.NET Core. В нем есть файл `web.config`, где лежит `connectionString`. И есть проект `Data Layer` (.NET Framework библиотека классов). В нем пытаюсь получить в конструкторе класса `connectionString` следующим образом:

```
public DataManager()
{    
    ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString.ToString();
}
```

Дело в том, что в сам конструктор отладчик даже не заходит, перед этим выбрасывается `FileNotFoundException`:

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified."

Можно ли как-то получить строку подключения в проекте `.NET Framework class library` из `web.config`, находящегося в `ASP.NET Core` проекте?

Comment: Нужно сборку подключить и ко второму проекту. Даже если она в нём не используется напрямую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите nuget пакет `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` в проекте asp.net core

```
PM> Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.5.0
```